# Como seleccionar un JButton automáticamente

Tags: java, eventos, botón

Necesito que cuando se ejecute un método que el `JButton` que muestro en la imagen le aparezca el contorno azul que le rodea, es decir, que se seleccione para así depues cuando se pulse el botón enter (u otra tecla) se ejecute el evento `jButtonKeyPressed` y se ejecute un método que contiene el evento. He probado con muchos métodos `jButton.set()` pero no he conseguido que ninguno me funcione. ¿Sabeis alguna manera para que le aparezca al `JButton` de manera automática el contorno azul, es decir, que se quede marcado?.

Muchas gracias.

[image: Botón]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ejecuta el método requestFocus() del boton que deseas marcar

```
jButton.requestFocus();
```